# No Bluetooth hardware detected on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have upgraded from [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine) to [20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), but in neither of them, Bluetooth doesn't work (Wi-Fi works).

Laptop: HP 15-da1009ne

Wi-Fi: RTL8822BE

Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4.2

How can I fix this problem? (I haven't yet been able to test [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) or [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver).)

[image]

Comment: Please provide the model of your laptop. What do you mean by it does not work? Please runt the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade commands. There are instructions here for how to pair bluetooth headphones: https://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset

Comment: @CFCBazarcom On the settings page, it says no Bluetooth device found. The laptop's model has been specified previously.

Comment: Sorry about that I did not see the laptop model. I think Ubuntu does not support your bluetooth driver and an external bluetooth dongle might be necessary(they are cheap). Can you please do something for me? If you have a Windows installation, check this video of how to get the hardware IDs for the video card, but instead give me the hardware IDs for the bluetooth. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSHC6gN6t48

Comment: @CFCBazarcom

First: USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B00B&REV_0110    

Second: USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B00B

Comment: Try this: 
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15.git
sudo dkms add ./newbtfix-4.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0

Comment: The whole answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working

Comment: Re *"Bluetooth doesn't work"*: Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*